# Increasing the corner radius of UITextField removes its shadow

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a UITextField with custom code to control the corner radius and the placeholder color and another different properties. Also, I have a Protocol with Extension to drop shadow from any UI element.

The problem is: whenever I increase the corner radius of the text field, I lose the shadow. As long as the corner radius is 0, I still have a shadow.

And this shows at the debugger when I increase the cornerRadius and lose the shadow:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key height
```

Here is my Protocol I implemented to drop shadow:

```
import UIKit

protocol DropShadow {}

extension DropShadow where Self: UIView {

    func addDropShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)
        layer.shadowRadius = 3
    }
}
```

And here is my custom class for the UITextField:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class FancyTextField: UITextField, DropShadow {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bgColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = bgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var placeHolderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            let rawString = attributedPlaceholder?.string != nil ? attributedPlaceholder!.string : ""
            let str = NSAttributedString(string: rawString, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeHolderColor!])
            attributedPlaceholder = str
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a corner radius to a `UIView` you have to set the `clipsToBounds` or `masksToBounds` to be true. That doesn't allow the shadow to be created as the shadow is created **outside** the bounds.

As a solution for this problem, you will have to create a `superView` to the `UIView` that has the clipped corners, and add a shadow to this `superView` (Make sure to set the superview to clear color)

Comment: Its nothing wrong with your code. Changing the `layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0` will remove the corner radius but add the shadow. 

Like i said you will have to create a `UIView` and add a shadow to it and add the view you are adding a corner radius to, inside of it as a subview. Basically apply `cornerRadius` code and drop shadow to two separate views.

Comment: Thank your for your time helping the community being a collaborative place, Rikh. I appreciate it.